# Which ads does this privilege remove?

Tags: discussion, advertising

[The privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) says

> **What is reduced advertisements?**
>
> As a courtesy to our avid users, we automatically disable some ads when they reach this reputation level.
>
> **How do I know it's working?**
>
> After you achieve this privilege, the two "leaderboard" style ads will be automatically suppressed from question pages when you are logged in.

Except for [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916820/querying-compositetype-columns-in-cassandra-using-hector) I have never seen leaderboard ads.

Why is this privilege listed anywhere else?

---

**EDIT**

A specific example I had in mind is http://judaism.stackexchange.com . As shown in gnat's screenshot, there is a 'reduce ads' privilege, yet no ads to be reduced.

I just looked up other Beta site and it looks like only http://judaism.stackexchange.com has this privilege. I don't know why it has it while say, https://history.stackexchange.com/privileges https://bricks.stackexchange.com/privileges https://travel.stackexchange.com/privileges do not.

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker?

Comment: @Oded no ()()()()

Comment: The ads exist on ServerFault as well, but not SuperUser. At least, I don't see any, and I don't have anything blocking them.

Comment: Most of the sites don't have ads like this, but the general theory is that they will when they reach the appropriate size.  The privilege works the same way on all sites, so there's no need to customize it.

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't think any Beta sites have ads, so why do they have this privilege?

Comment: @Shmuel Like I said, hopefully they *will* have ads later, so why bother to do the work to customize them?  It doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @MatthewRead privilege on Beta is different than that of the final site.

Comment: To see the difference, logout from a Stack Exchange site, and see the difference.

Comment: @kiamlaluno **Except for stackoverflow.com** I have never seen leaderboard ads.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I have seen those ads in other sites too, but I cannot say if something has been changed in the while. It could be those ads are less frequently seen, nowadays, but I don't have any evidence that is true. The sites where I should see them are also the sites that I visit very rarely.

Answer (score 11):

I just tested how things look for unprivileged users at SO.

There's an ad for *Careers* displayed when I am logged out. This ad disappears when I log in and let my reputation take care of that privilege:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVaPK.jpg]

At ServerFault it was even easier to test: with my less-than-200 rep there this ad is visible when I am logged in.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhABz.png]

At SuperUser though the ad is not displayed. Per discussion in comments to the question it looks like *general theory is that ads will appear when sites reach the appropriate size*.

---

## update

At [judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges) *reduce ads* is displayed while ads aren't there. This looks like a bug to me.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qep7z.jpg]

Comment: I know. My question is about other sites (and even more so Beta)

Comment: @ShmuelBrill At ServerFault it was even easier to test: with my less-than-200 rep there this ad is visible when I am logged in. Looks like as Matthew noted in comments to your question, **general theory is that ads will appear when sites reach the appropriate size**

Comment: Beta will never reach that size. So why does Beta have this privilege?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill Beta? I don't follow sorry. I just checked http://money.stackexchange.com/privileges and http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges - none lists _reduce ads_ to me

Comment: @gnat They're on the non-beta [diy.se] or [scifi.se] either. MSO might be the only site without ads which has the privilege.

Comment: @gnat http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges

Comment: @ShmuelBrill indeed - thanks! I updated the answer with screen shot showing the bug at judaism

Comment: I don't usually consider ads to be true ads if they're from the same organization/company, so unless they're "loud" (blinking, bright yellow, etc.) it's no big deal - especially if they're good, like SO's jobs. It's a feature!